# CSS: How to place next to each other 2 images with 50 % width?

Tags: css, image, position

I want to place two images each of unspecified height and width 50 % of the page next to each other. They should be in the same height and they should resize as user changes width of the browser window. How can I do this in CSS without using `position: fixed;`or `position: absolute;`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just make give them `width: 50%` in CSS. The images are inline blocks and will be nicely next to each other, as long as you make sure there is no whitespace inbetween them:

```css
img {
    width: 50%;
}
```

```html
<img src="http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/7/70/Example.png"><img src="http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/7/70/Example.png">
```